# How to change Nodejs etimeout time?

Tags: node.js

I have a question about the etimedout time in NodeJS.
How do I change the etimedout time from 20 seconds to 5 seconds?

```
connection.on('connect',function () {
  console.log('blabal');
}).on('error',function(){
   console.log('blabal');
});
```

So if I can't connect the etimedout message will be shown after 20 seconds I want to change it to 5 seconds.It's a thrift connection btw :)

Greetz,

Frank

Comment: By etimeout are you referring to a http request timeout, or a delay from the timers module http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html?

Comment: Sorry forgot to notice it's a http request timeout see my edited message.

Answer (score 0):

From the API docs, http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback:

`connection.setTimeout(5000);`

Comment: It's a thrift connection, I already tried setTimeout no luck. I looked up the thrift too no results.

Comment: This should set the timeout on the underlying socket so it shouldn't make a difference on the receiving end. What's the other end of the socket?

Comment: It's a JAVA server so I want to check if it's online. So if I want to connect and it's offline than I get an ETIMEDOUT error. This error will show every 20 seconds, but I want to decrease this time. I hope Im clear to you ;)

Comment: What module are you using to make the request? http?